# Adding one corrplot graph on top of another

Tags: r, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

this is my first question on StackOverflow so I hope it'll be specific enough.

I have a correlation matrix for a series of financial data for 2 different time periods (`corr.pre` and `corr.post`) and would like to put the two `corrplot.mixed` graphs that I created on top of each other; specifically in the lower part I would like to put the correlations of both in numbers and in the upper part the correlations with the `'ellipse'` method (this way any change in the ellipses would be easily noticeable).

unfortunately `add=TRUE` is not working for me. Do you have any suggestion to fix it or to get around this issue?

This is my code at the moment:

```
corrplot.mixed(corr_pre, order = 'alphabet', lower = 'number', lower.col = 'black', number.cex = 1.3, upper = 'ellipse',upper.col = colorRampPalette(c("darkred","white","midnightblue"))(100), outline = TRUE, tl.pos = 'lt', tl.col = 'black', tl.cex = 1.5, title = 'Market', cex.main = 2.5,tl.srt = 45, diag = 'u', mar = c(0, 0, 3, 0), cl.cex = 1.5)


corrplot.mixed(corr_post, order = 'alphabet', lower = 'number', lower.col = 'red', number.cex = 1.3, upper = 'ellipse',upper.col = colorRampPalette(c("darkred","white","midnightblue"))(100), outline = TRUE, tl.pos = 'lt', tl.col = 'black', tl.cex = 1.5, title = 'Market', cex.main = 2.5,tl.srt = 45, diag = 'u', mar = c(0, 0, 3, 0), cl.cex = 1.5, add = TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you reformat the code using a code block? It's a bit hard to read at the moment.

Comment: Thank you Venantius, the question is modified now

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following to add two matrices on top of each other:

1. keep the `order` either original or alphabet as you did in your
   reprex
2. make the `type` of one upper and the other should be lower
3. turn off the labels for one of the matrices by `tl.pos = "n"`
4. turn off the legend for one of the matrices by `cl.pos = "n"`
5. include the parameter `add = TRUE` for the second matrix

Now once you run the code for the first matrix in R, you get a half matrix but while you are viewing it run the code for the second matrix, you should get a complete hybrid matrix. If you don't, then try multiple times until you get one. Use dev.off() to turn off any left over devices, and start over until you get the desired result.
You can finally save your final matrix by :

```
corHybridPlot <- recordPlot()
```

I hope this helps.